# DROPCLEANBUFFERS does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which I am trying to optimize. In order to know how much time is spent for an execution I have added at the beginning of the script:

```
use MyDatabase
go
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO
```

between two execution I can see the time to run the query decreasing. I thought only cache could fasten the execution of my script, are there other mechanism in SQL Server to do the trick?

thanks,

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) as well?

Comment: You should also take a look at using the query execution plans to figure out how to optimize your query instead of blowing out your cache every time you make a change.

Comment: thx swasheck. my question was more about the internals of sql server. In order to explain why the exact same query without caching could be faster every time I was using it.

Comment: because as Andomar answered, the optimizer stores the plan too, so it does not have to recompile the plan - it just pulls the plan from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you run a stored procedure, the query plan is calculated and compiled.  This typically takes 20ms, can be a bit more for a long procedure.

If you run the query once, before `checkpoint; dbcc dropcleanbuffers;`, the plan should be cached.

Comment: you mean: As I have run the query once. The next time I am running it, whether or not I am using heckpoint; dbcc dropcleanbuffers;, the query plan is already calculated and compiled, so that sql server will not do it again?

Comment: there is no command I could run to recalculate and recompile my whole query plan everytime?

Comment: Ah ah ah ok what was telling me  swasheck.. ok now i get it. Thanks to you both!